# The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, namespaces

I encounter this kind of error when I debug a project 
I already have `EntityFramework.dll`, `System.Core.dll`, `System.Data.Entity` but still `Core` is not referenced.

Can someone help me?

I'm having error in this Line

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

This is the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: What version of Entity Framework is in your project?

Answer (score 6):

Enrique, I had this problem crop up when I started opening a project on my desktop that I had normally been opening on my VM.  Masoud's answer is not helpful... I don't think he read your original post.

What I did to clear this compile error up was to open NuGet package manager and install the update that was available for EntityFramework.  I had version 6.1.1 installed in the project and I upgraded to 6.1.3.  I should not have had the error to start with, but upgrading the version appeared to jiggle whatever it was loose because I started compiling fine after that.

Comment: Similar... not worth another answer though. Happened when downloading sample code from an exercise though. Was already on the highest version, did an uninstall and reinstall of 6.1.3 and issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you add references from other sources than nuget manager (example: Local source) you need to verify the HintPath of that reference before moving your application in another environment