# The name 'Core' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I am following Xamarin University tutorial. Everything was working fine until I started running into the error `core does not exist`. I looked over an old question that was posted and I followed the instructions but this did not help me at all. I have posted the link to the old question below.

[The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092188/the-type-or-namespace-name-core-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace)

code for MainPage.xml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyTelephone
{   
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    Entry phoneNumberText;
    Button translateButton;
    Button callButton;
    string translatedNumber;




    public MainPage()
    {

        this.Padding = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20);

        StackLayout panel = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 15
        };

        panel.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Text = "Enter a password:",
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
        });

        panel.Children.Add(phoneNumberText = new Entry
        {
            Text = "1-855-XAMARIN",
        });

        panel.Children.Add(translateButton = new Button
        {
            Text = "Translate"
        });

        panel.Children.Add(callButton = new Button
        {
            Text = "Call",
            IsEnabled = false,
        });
        translateButton.Clicked += OnTranslate;

        this.Content = panel;

        //InitializeComponent();

    }


    private void OnTranslate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        translatedNumber = 
    Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(translatedNumber))
        {
            callButton.IsEnabled = true;
            callButton.Text = "Call" + translatedNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            callButton.IsEnabled = false;
            callButton.Text = "Call";
        }
    }


    }
}
```

code for PhonewordTranslator.cs

```
using System.Text;
namespace MyTelephone
{
    public static class PhonewordTranslator
   {
    public static string ToNumber(string raw)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(raw))
            return null;

        raw = raw.ToUpperInvariant();

        var newNumber = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var c in raw)
        {
            if ("-0123456789".Contains(c))
                newNumber.Append(c);
            else
            {
                var result = TranslateToNumber(c);
                if (result != null)
                    newNumber.Append(result);
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
        return newNumber.ToString();
    }
    static bool Contains(this string keyString, char c)
    {
        return keyString.IndexOf(c) >= 0;
    }

    static readonly string[] digits = {
        "ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS","TUV","WXYZ"
    };

    static int? TranslateToNumber(char c)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
        {
            if (digits[i].Contains(c))
                return 2 + i;
             }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't provide any detail that could be used to offer a different solution that works without guessing blindly.  We can't see your code.  Please share it.

Comment: added code. sorry about that.

Comment: I have to disagree with the close voters. Maybe they voted before the edit. But this is clearly an on topic question that doesn't just say "why isn't my code working"

Comment: @Mafii the close votes were made before code was added to the question.  At the time the question wasn't answerable.

Comment: Hence the "Maybe they voted before the edit" @Amy . Just wanted to be sure. I agree

Comment: Yes I'm aware you used that phrasing.  I was informing you that you were correct, not correcting you.

Comment: @Amy ah, sorry then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with xamarin, and nothing with the question you linked.

This is the reason for the error:

```
translatedNumber = 
Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
```

Check your file PhoneTranslator.cs it. You need to rename the namespace.

Source:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13839/core-phonewordtranslator-tonumber-compilation-error

> For those people needing more information, this issue can be caused by not renaming the namespace in the PhoneTranslator.cs file to "Core".

Comment: what should I rename it to?

Comment: The issue can be caused by not renaming it to "Core", so maybe you should rename it to "Core".

Comment: @jsilva rename it to `Core` or access it by the namespace you put it in. @Mafii I wouldn't call this an error in Xamarin more so an error cut and pasting this `PhonewordTranslator` code.

Comment: oh okay my namespace is `MyTelephone` so it should be `MyTelephone.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);`

Comment: yes. @JSteward I agree, hence I never called it a "xamarin error", rather than "to do with xamarin" which I agree is far fetched but... More accurate than calling it an error anyways

Comment: @JSteward go ahead and edit it if you feel like you've got a better term for it. I'll happily let it be.